# Is there any component that renders list in ReactJs equivalent to FlatList in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i need a suggestion for how to build a component that reacts the same way as FlatList . Or maybe there is a ready tool to do it in react JS . Here is my simple FlatList of react native :

```
             <FlatList

             data={this.props.list_data}
             horizontal={false}

             renderItem={this.renderItemList}

             keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString() }
             refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
             onRefresh={() => this.props.onRefresh()}
                  / >
```

Here in react native FlatList it takes data which is an object and renders a list . So how can i do the same behviour with react js list ?
when doing like that

```
           const listarray = Object.values(this.props.data)
          return (
            <ul >
            {listarray.map(function(item) {
               return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
                   })}
                </ul>   )
```

This way i get this error :

```
          Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. 
          Keys should be unique so that components maintain their 
          identity 
          across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be 
          duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and 
          could change in a future version.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you probably have 2 items that are exactly the same.

Just use something else as the key for every single item.

As said by the error, you cannot use the same key for 2 components inside a `.map`. The simplest way to is to use the index.

```
 {listarray.map(function(item,index) {
           return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
               })}
```

Comment: thank u so much it solves the problem of key but still have an error because data in FlatList is an object : Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, DT_RowId, aps_color}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: can you give me an example of the list_data you are using?

Comment: Array(4)
0: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, DT_RowId: "row_98699"}
1: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, DT_RowId: "row_98701"}
2: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, DT_RowId: "row_121597"}
3: {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, DT_RowId: "row_121598"}

Comment: And how's the renderItemList function done? is it the one you are showing?

Comment: here is the render function:                                                    
        renderItemList(item) {
    return React.createElement(DocumentListElement, {
      action: this.props.data.action,
      numColumns:2,
      mod_id: this.props.list_aps_header.mod_id,
      column: this.props.list_aps_columns,
      row: item
    });
  }